# Haskell MArray of Maybes

Tags: haskell

I want to have a mutable array with boxed elements of type `Maybe a`. This function should be able to be used when `e :: Maybe Int`, but also when `e :: Maybe Char`, etc.

```
initBF :: (MArray a e m) => Int -> m (a G.Node e)
initBF n = newArray (1::G.Node, n) Nothing
```

And here is the compiler error

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘e’ with ‘Maybe a0’
      ‘e’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          initBF :: forall (a :: * -> * -> *) e (m :: * -> *).
                    MArray a e m =>
                    Int -> m (a G.Node e)
        at src/BellmanFord.hs:14:1-49
      Expected type: m (a G.Node e)
        Actual type: m (a G.Node (Maybe a0))
    • In the expression: newArray (1 :: G.Node, n) Nothing
      In an equation for ‘initBF’:
          initBF n = newArray (1 :: G.Node, n) Nothing
    • Relevant bindings include
        initBF :: Int -> m (a G.Node e) (bound at src/BellmanFord.hs:15:1)
   |
15 | initBF n = newArray (1::G.Node, n) Nothing
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

If I do a substition of `e` by `Maybe a0` then I get the error `Not type-variable argument in the constraint (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)`.

Should I use FlexibleContexts or is there something else I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly specify that the elements should be `Maybe e`:

```hs
initBF :: (MArray a (Maybe e) m) => Int -> m (a G.Node (Maybe e))
initBF n = newArray (1::G.Node, n) Nothing
```

You **will** need `FlexibleContents`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use FlexibleContexts.